# jcoverflip customisation

Tags: jquery

i just found jcoverflip
it's a great script but i'd like to customise it.
instead of this scrollbar i'd like to use simple left/right arrows
what function do i have to call?
i found functions called next and previous but i don't know how to call them properly.
the js is here -> http://www.jcoverflip.com/files/docs/jcoverflip-demo/jquery.jcoverflip.js
and this is how i wanted to call this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('left').click(function() {
this.previous();
//this.previous();
} );
});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    $('.left').click(function() {
        var i = $('#flip').jcoverflip("next");
        i.next();
    });
    $('.right').click(function () {
        var i = $('#flip').jcoverflip("previous");
        i.next();
    });
```

Assuming the buttons you are targeting use the classes 'left' and 'right'.